# How to launch instance in openstack when error says "no valid hosts found"?

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, nova

I've deployed openstack using juju on maas. I've created few images and trying to launch a new instance like CirrOs test instance. I'm getting error saying "no valid hosts found". I've checked my nodes which are running and communicating fine. What should I do to successfully launch an instance.

Here is the /var/log/nova/nova-scheduler.log.1 on nova-cloud-controller node:

```
    2014-09-24 10:50:43.764 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:50:43.764 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:50:44.774 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:51:14.797 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:51:14.798 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:51:15.807 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:51:45.814 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:51:45.815 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:51:46.825 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:52:16.846 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:52:16.847 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:52:17.856 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:52:47.882 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:52:47.882 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:52:48.893 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:53:18.918 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:53:18.918 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:53:19.928 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:53:49.953 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:53:49.953 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:53:50.963 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:54:20.964 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:54:20.964 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:54:21.974 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:54:51.999 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:54:51.999 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:54:53.008 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:55:23.034 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:55:23.034 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:55:24.044 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:55:54.047 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:55:54.047 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:55:55.057 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:56:25.073 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:56:25.073 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:56:26.083 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:56:56.107 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:56:56.107 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:56:57.116 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:57:27.138 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:57:27.139 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:57:28.148 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:57:58.156 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:57:58.156 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:57:59.165 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:58:29.186 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:58:29.186 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:58:30.196 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:59:00.215 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:59:00.215 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:59:01.225 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 10:59:31.247 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 10:59:31.247 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 10:59:32.257 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 11:00:02.261 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 11:00:02.261 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 11:00:03.271 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 11:00:33.294 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 11:00:33.294 5430 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 11:00:34.304 5430 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
2014-09-24 11:00:43.930 5430 INFO nova.openstack.common.service [-] Caught SIGTERM, exiting
2014-09-24 11:00:45.198 18145 INFO nova.openstack.common.periodic_task [-] Skipping periodic task _periodic_update_dns because its interval is negative
2014-09-24 11:00:45.253 18145 AUDIT nova.service [-] Starting scheduler node (version 2014.1.2)
2014-09-24 11:00:46.030 18145 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 1 seconds.
2014-09-24 11:00:47.031 18145 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 11:00:47.031 18145 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 11:00:48.041 18145 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 3 seconds.
2014-09-24 11:00:51.041 18145 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 11:00:51.042 18145 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 11:00:52.052 18145 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 5 seconds.
2014-09-24 11:00:57.056 18145 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 11:00:57.057 18145 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 11:00:58.066 18145 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 7 seconds.
2014-09-24 11:01:05.069 18145 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 11:01:05.069 18145 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 11:01:06.079 18145 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 9 seconds.
2014-09-24 11:01:15.083 18145 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 11:01:15.083 18145 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 11:01:16.092 18145 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 11 seconds.
2014-09-24 11:01:22.302 18145 INFO nova.openstack.common.service [-] Caught SIGTERM, exiting
2014-09-24 11:01:23.404 19984 INFO nova.openstack.common.periodic_task [-] Skipping periodic task _periodic_update_dns because its interval is negative
2014-09-24 11:01:23.458 19984 AUDIT nova.service [-] Starting scheduler node (version 2014.1.2)
2014-09-24 11:01:24.378 19984 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 1 seconds.
2014-09-24 11:01:25.381 19984 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on localhost:5672
2014-09-24 11:01:25.381 19984 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2014-09-24 11:01:26.391 19984 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on localhost:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 3 seconds.
2014-09-24 11:01:27.278 19984 INFO nova.openstack.common.service [-] Caught SIGTERM, exiting
2014-09-24 11:01:28.400 20405 INFO nova.openstack.common.periodic_task [-] Skipping periodic task _periodic_update_dns because its interval is negative
2014-09-24 11:01:28.454 20405 AUDIT nova.service [-] Starting scheduler node (version 2014.1.2)
2014-09-24 11:01:29.413 20405 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Connected to AMQP server on 192.168.2.164:5672
2014-09-24 11:02:16.800 20405 INFO nova.openstack.common.service [-] Caught SIGTERM, exiting
2014-09-24 11:02:17.940 23317 INFO nova.openstack.common.periodic_task [-] Skipping periodic task _periodic_update_dns because its interval is negative
2014-09-24 11:02:17.995 23317 AUDIT nova.service [-] Starting scheduler node (version 2014.1.2)
2014-09-24 11:02:18.757 23317 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Connected to AMQP server on 192.168.2.164:5672
2014-09-24 11:02:54.298 23317 INFO nova.openstack.common.service [-] Caught SIGTERM, exiting
2014-09-24 11:02:55.533 25504 INFO nova.openstack.common.periodic_task [-] Skipping periodic task _periodic_update_dns because its interval is negative
2014-09-24 11:02:55.618 25504 AUDIT nova.service [-] Starting scheduler node (version 2014.1.2)
2014-09-24 11:02:56.305 25504 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Connected to AMQP server on 192.168.2.164:5672
2014-09-25 06:43:03.644 25504 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-4464a07d-dc3a-459d-8d37-51461fc93d47 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'61ba201a-3c6b-4694-9c0a-798ba6cb371a']
2014-09-25 06:43:03.670 25504 INFO nova.filters [req-4464a07d-dc3a-459d-8d37-51461fc93d47 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 06:43:03.670 25504 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-4464a07d-dc3a-459d-8d37-51461fc93d47 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: 61ba201a-3c6b-4694-9c0a-798ba6cb371a] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-25 06:43:03.759 25504 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Connected to AMQP server on 192.168.2.164:5672
2014-09-25 08:29:54.275 25504 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-ef42fbc2-6cb2-48f5-94b9-fee8304d1809 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'bbe50d9f-28f1-4795-88d1-944495ae1453']
2014-09-25 08:29:54.294 25504 INFO nova.filters [req-ef42fbc2-6cb2-48f5-94b9-fee8304d1809 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 08:29:54.294 25504 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-ef42fbc2-6cb2-48f5-94b9-fee8304d1809 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: bbe50d9f-28f1-4795-88d1-944495ae1453] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-25 08:32:47.835 25504 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-5c88d990-8a35-43e4-ad66-6fe55ce7eafd 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'538799de-fd1f-43ef-9cc7-53ce489179c6']
2014-09-25 08:32:47.853 25504 INFO nova.filters [req-5c88d990-8a35-43e4-ad66-6fe55ce7eafd 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 08:32:47.853 25504 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-5c88d990-8a35-43e4-ad66-6fe55ce7eafd 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: 538799de-fd1f-43ef-9cc7-53ce489179c6] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-25 08:33:47.946 25504 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-6d3d44d3-a346-4560-8ecb-69d06fbe1905 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'a17c6e9e-69b1-4d6d-a15b-2ac9db773838']
2014-09-25 08:33:47.964 25504 INFO nova.filters [req-6d3d44d3-a346-4560-8ecb-69d06fbe1905 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 08:33:47.965 25504 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-6d3d44d3-a346-4560-8ecb-69d06fbe1905 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: a17c6e9e-69b1-4d6d-a15b-2ac9db773838] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-25 09:59:45.127 25504 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-90bebd50-e5e0-4b47-b923-7aa33089b813 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'607908ca-394d-47c0-94c1-bbc8e86fa660']
2014-09-25 09:59:45.145 25504 INFO nova.filters [req-90bebd50-e5e0-4b47-b923-7aa33089b813 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 09:59:45.145 25504 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-90bebd50-e5e0-4b47-b923-7aa33089b813 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: 607908ca-394d-47c0-94c1-bbc8e86fa660] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-25 10:03:24.544 25504 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-4b2d6fe8-58f0-4bc6-9ddc-a7c832f740a4 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'402124fe-f560-4737-b98e-32a4ae37aa70']
2014-09-25 10:03:24.568 25504 INFO nova.filters [req-4b2d6fe8-58f0-4bc6-9ddc-a7c832f740a4 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 10:03:24.568 25504 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-4b2d6fe8-58f0-4bc6-9ddc-a7c832f740a4 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: 402124fe-f560-4737-b98e-32a4ae37aa70] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-25 10:05:41.354 25504 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-ca765ead-ca80-4ce1-8a6d-a444c39dc578 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'8f82b1cd-c65a-453a-bd8d-18ed2c83646c']
2014-09-25 10:05:41.375 25504 INFO nova.filters [req-ca765ead-ca80-4ce1-8a6d-a444c39dc578 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 10:05:41.376 25504 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-ca765ead-ca80-4ce1-8a6d-a444c39dc578 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: 8f82b1cd-c65a-453a-bd8d-18ed2c83646c] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-25 10:13:01.935 25504 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-821bc614-f047-498e-a69d-bcc5b06cf4ab 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'47d1df54-8a6f-4472-9215-764d0ef507f4']
2014-09-25 10:13:01.955 25504 INFO nova.filters [req-821bc614-f047-498e-a69d-bcc5b06cf4ab 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 10:13:01.956 25504 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-821bc614-f047-498e-a69d-bcc5b06cf4ab 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: 47d1df54-8a6f-4472-9215-764d0ef507f4] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-25 10:36:42.558 25504 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-39fb8b95-e56d-4ed6-a04f-86839afee2d5 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'9df87eb4-6e6f-4e7b-928b-bd565483370f']
2014-09-25 10:36:42.579 25504 INFO nova.filters [req-39fb8b95-e56d-4ed6-a04f-86839afee2d5 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 10:36:42.579 25504 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-39fb8b95-e56d-4ed6-a04f-86839afee2d5 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: 9df87eb4-6e6f-4e7b-928b-bd565483370f] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-25 10:40:31.921 25504 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-74ede1ae-4e28-40c7-b243-67de3f1cac2c 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'b3a1190a-ddca-4744-adcf-5e3777d0c352']
2014-09-25 10:40:31.941 25504 INFO nova.filters [req-74ede1ae-4e28-40c7-b243-67de3f1cac2c 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 10:40:31.942 25504 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-74ede1ae-4e28-40c7-b243-67de3f1cac2c 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: b3a1190a-ddca-4744-adcf-5e3777d0c352] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-25 10:44:13.720 25504 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-ab53af98-0a94-4295-871e-0249961eaf88 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'aa3e900a-ddf7-480f-8614-52d10634a9eb']
2014-09-25 10:44:13.740 25504 INFO nova.filters [req-ab53af98-0a94-4295-871e-0249961eaf88 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 10:44:13.740 25504 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-ab53af98-0a94-4295-871e-0249961eaf88 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: aa3e900a-ddf7-480f-8614-52d10634a9eb] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-25 10:49:21.515 25504 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-ea16af66-2548-4748-ab58-263a0be590bb 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'd8df7971-05d9-4cac-be8c-9ebc3e25d37d']
2014-09-25 10:49:21.535 25504 INFO nova.filters [req-ea16af66-2548-4748-ab58-263a0be590bb 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 10:49:21.535 25504 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-ea16af66-2548-4748-ab58-263a0be590bb 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: d8df7971-05d9-4cac-be8c-9ebc3e25d37d] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-25 10:56:04.325 25504 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-56446220-9404-417a-92e6-8d5179551271 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'bfc41971-e1df-461d-afd8-c7aaf5da0190']
2014-09-25 10:56:04.349 25504 INFO nova.filters [req-56446220-9404-417a-92e6-8d5179551271 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 10:56:04.349 25504 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-56446220-9404-417a-92e6-8d5179551271 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: bfc41971-e1df-461d-afd8-c7aaf5da0190] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-25 11:04:41.574 25504 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-0ba850c6-0686-448d-8b13-273fb8f4d95f 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'6b444eb3-c404-4633-bf39-a97ebc247eeb']
2014-09-25 11:04:41.595 25504 INFO nova.filters [req-0ba850c6-0686-448d-8b13-273fb8f4d95f 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 11:04:41.596 25504 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-0ba850c6-0686-448d-8b13-273fb8f4d95f 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: 6b444eb3-c404-4633-bf39-a97ebc247eeb] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-25 11:08:39.379 25504 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-0610d413-db29-4e06-8dd2-bf9933a72d1a 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'084863cc-dd3c-465f-9374-b2cbf527b15b']
2014-09-25 11:08:39.400 25504 INFO nova.filters [req-0610d413-db29-4e06-8dd2-bf9933a72d1a 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 11:08:39.401 25504 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-0610d413-db29-4e06-8dd2-bf9933a72d1a 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: 084863cc-dd3c-465f-9374-b2cbf527b15b] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-25 11:47:38.453 25504 INFO nova.openstack.common.service [-] Caught SIGTERM, exiting
2014-09-25 11:53:31.929 1347 INFO nova.openstack.common.periodic_task [-] Skipping periodic task _periodic_update_dns because its interval is negative
2014-09-25 11:53:32.125 1347 AUDIT nova.service [-] Starting scheduler node (version 2014.1.2)
2014-09-25 11:53:33.263 1347 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Connected to AMQP server on 192.168.2.164:5672
2014-09-25 11:55:18.053 1347 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-5cac5be1-e99b-4880-8234-9474de5bc991 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'f66a30ba-edcc-4b0e-9a14-8fad66f0ba85']
2014-09-25 11:55:18.078 1347 INFO nova.filters [req-5cac5be1-e99b-4880-8234-9474de5bc991 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 11:55:18.079 1347 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-5cac5be1-e99b-4880-8234-9474de5bc991 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: f66a30ba-edcc-4b0e-9a14-8fad66f0ba85] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-25 11:55:18.186 1347 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Connected to AMQP server on 192.168.2.164:5672
2014-09-25 12:18:16.369 1347 INFO nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler [req-133a6f37-3001-4d36-8474-48376d697700 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Attempting to build 1 instance(s) uuids: [u'60161baa-ef77-4075-9cae-d9f7ebb88773']
2014-09-25 12:18:16.390 1347 INFO nova.filters [req-133a6f37-3001-4d36-8474-48376d697700 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] Filter ImagePropertiesFilter returned 0 hosts
2014-09-25 12:18:16.391 1347 WARNING nova.scheduler.driver [req-133a6f37-3001-4d36-8474-48376d697700 40081531691e4bc6a82e6345a1b932d3 60e79824fac24362af1ea035f4a964e8] [instance: 60161baa-ef77-4075-9cae-d9f7ebb88773] Setting instance to ERROR state.
2014-09-26 05:09:40.881 1347 INFO nova.openstack.common.service [-] Caught SIGTERM, exiting
2014-09-26 05:11:57.636 1365 INFO nova.openstack.common.periodic_task [-] Skipping periodic task _periodic_update_dns because its interval is negative
2014-09-26 05:11:57.778 1365 AUDIT nova.service [-] Starting scheduler node (version 2014.1.2)
2014-09-26 05:11:58.708 1365 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Connected to AMQP server on 192.168.2.164:5672
2014-09-26 05:12:24.391 1365 INFO nova.openstack.common.service [-] Caught SIGTERM, exiting
2014-09-26 05:12:25.666 4535 INFO nova.openstack.common.periodic_task [-] Skipping periodic task _periodic_update_dns because its interval is negative
2014-09-26 05:12:25.724 4535 AUDIT nova.service [-] Starting scheduler node (version 2014.1.2)
2014-09-26 05:12:26.632 4535 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Connected to AMQP server on 192.168.2.164:5672
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in `/var/log/nova/nova-scheduler.log`. You should find some hints there why the scheduler could not deploy the node.

Comment: Its showing nothing, the file /var/log/nova/nova-scheduler.log on nova-cloud-controller node is empty

Comment: I've updated my question with log. @Ruediger please check this. :)

Comment: What does `nova-manage service list` show?

Comment: Its showing something like :-) and status enabled in front of services like binary, nova-cert, nova-scheduler, nova-conductor...

Comment: Binary   Host    Zone             Status     State Updated_At
nova-cert    nodethreehcl   internal  enabled    :-)   2014-09-26 11:53:19
nova-scheduler   nodethreehcl  internal   enabled    :-)   2014-09-26 11:53:19
nova-conductor   nodethreehcl  internal  enabled    :-)   2014-09-26 11:53:20
nova-compute     nodefourdell   nova   enabled    :-)   2014-09-26 11:53:23
nova-network     nodefourdell   internal  enabled    :-)   2014-09-26 11:53:23
nova-compute     nodefivedell  nova   enabled    :-)   2014-09-26 11:53:25
nova-network     nodefivedell internal  enabled    :-)   2014-09-26 11:53:18